# Popup window doesn't work

Tags: gis, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to create a popup window in a map. I have tree layers in my program; the first two layers are working; the third layer where I have template is defined doesn't work, though. In the console I get following errors:

> Error: Unable to draw graphic (null): Unable to complete operation.
>   ...usePost,v=h.crossOrigin):A=!!h);g=e.mixin({},g);g._ssl&&(g.url=g.url.replace(/^h...

I tried to solve this problem, by adding time between the layers. It didn't work. 
Below is my code. Please let me know if I am making any mistake. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <!--The viewport meta tag is used to improve the presentation and behavior of the samples
        on iOS devices-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
        <title> Trees Location</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/esri/css/esri.css">
      <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/"></script>
        <script>
        var map;
    require(["esri/config", "esri/map","esri/dijit/Popup",
      "dojo/dom-construct",
      "esri/dijit/PopupTemplate",
      "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
       "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
        "esri/tasks/GeometryService",
     "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
     "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer", 
      "esri/Color",
     "dojo/domReady!"],
    function (esriConfig, Map,Popup,domConstruct, PopupTemplate, FeatureLayer,SimpleMarkerSymbol, GeometryService, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer, Color ) {

 esriConfig.defaults.geometryService = new GeometryService("http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");
            var popupOptions = {
            markerSymbol: new SimpleMarkerSymbol("circle", 32, null,
              new Color([0, 0, 0, 0.25])),
            marginLeft: "20",
            marginTop: "20"
          };
    var popup = new Popup(popupOptions, domConstruct.create("div"));
    map = new Map("map", {                
        center: [-76.756, 40.241],
        zoom: 8,
     infoWindow: popup
    }); 
            var popupTemplate = new PopupTemplate({
            title: "{MEMORIAL}",
            fieldInfos: [
              {
                fieldName: "TREEDONOR",
                visible: true,
                label: "Type"
              },
                            {
                fieldName: "TREESPECIES",
                visible: true,
                label: "Type"
              },
              {
                fieldName: "TREEVARIETY",
                visible: true,
                label: "Type"
              }
              ]
          });

   var customBasemap = new   ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(
    "");
     map.addLayer(customBasemap); 
    /* setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("pausing a few seconds");
    map.addLayer(customBasemap);
},1000); */
  var treeLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(
    ""); 
    // map.addLayer(treeLayer); 
        setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("pausing a few seconds");
    map.addLayer(treeLayer);
},1000);

 var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("",
            {
              infoTemplate: popupTemplate,
              outFields: ["TREEDONOR","TREESPECIES","TREEVARIETY", "MEMORIAL"]
            });
            featureLayer.setDefinitionExpression("MEMORIAL != ''");
            map.addLayer(featureLayer); 
}); 

</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
<div align="center"><strong> Trees Listing &nbsp;&nbsp;</strong><hr>
<i><a target="_self" href="listingtrees.html">Listing</a> | <a target="_self" href="locationtrees.html">Locations </a></i>
</div>
<br>
<div id="map" >
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What tool you are work with?

Comment: @folibis - I am working in aptana 2.0